# How to take changes from one remote branch to other remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, jira

I'm working on a project and I cut a branch from a *release_branch* let's call my branch *branch_A*. My colleague also had cut another branch from same release branch and lets call that *branch_B*. We are working on the same file and section hence to avoid any merge conflicts I wanted to take changes from *branch_B* to my *branch_A*. Changes of *branch_B* has already been merged into that *release_branch* from which we had cut our branches earlier.

Can somebody tell what should I do? I've tried pull but it didn't work. Also I switched to the *release_branch* and took pull and changes were there but as soon as I switched to my *branch_A* the changes were gone. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you commit all changes to your `branch_A` and if you are concerned about losing your work as part of the process, create a new branch at `branch_A` (e.g. `branch_A_old`).

Since you will eventually be merging back to `release_branch`, you can use one of the following approaches:

1. Checkout `branch_A`, if not already, then pull from `remote_name/release_branch` into `branch_A` using `git pull --no-rebase remote_name/release_branch`.  This will create a merge commit, merging the latest `release_branch`, including changes made by `branch_B` into your branch.  If there are any conflicts, you will have to resolve them and perform a commit to complete the merge.
2. Checkout `branch_A`, fetch `remote_name/release_branch`, then merge `remote_name/release_branch` into `branch_A`.  This is basically the same as method 1, but broken into two steps.
3. Checkout `branch_A`, fetch `remote_name/release_branch`, then rebase `branch_A` using `remote_name/release_branch` as the upstream branch.  Alternatively, you can use use `git pull --rebase remote_name/release_branch` to combine the fetch and rebase into one step.

Methods 1 and 2 will keep the merge as part of the history and method 3 will update all of the commits in your branch so that your branch begins at the latest commit of `release_branch`.

Methods 1 and 2 are usually easier, although this is debatable, but method 3 will provide a cleaner history.  If you do use method 1 or 2, you can always perform a squash later to clean up the history.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just have couple of questions. "Checkout branch_A" I hope it means move to branch_A if iI'm present in any other branch. Second is what command to use for pull? I think simply doing `git pull` will just take changes from branch_A only. Should it be `git pull remote_name/release_branch --rebase`?

Comment: @PrateekGautam Yes.  The checkout step is only necessary if `branch_A` is not already checked out.  Command `git pull remote_name/release_branch --no-rebase` would work if you want to merge the remote branch in (method 1).  Command `git pull remote_name/release_branch --rebase` will combine the fetch and rebase into one step and have the same result as method 3.